# R ordered logit regression polr

Tags: r, ordered-logit

I have result from R: polars

```
polr(formula = cat ~ log_pop21 + birth + ngrw, data = new_df, 
    na.action = na.omit, Hess = T, method = "logistic")

Coefficients:
 log_pop21      birth       ngrw 
 3.1346164  1.0315305 -0.2486664 

Intercepts:
     0|1      1|2      2|3      3|4      4|5 
10.04250 12.66218 15.00460 18.26514 20.93464
```

How to interpret intercepts and coefficients specifically for my data? I've read so much documentation but can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand it, which is a little hand-waivy but, I think it's broadly correct. I'd be happy to be corrected, or somebody to explain it a little more technically but I hope this helps:

###### Intercepts

Ordered logistic regression works by modelling an unobserved continuous variable, that is put into its observed categories by the various cutpoints (which are called `Intercepts` here). Any value below 10.04 on the unobserved variable will be assigned 0, between 10.04 and 12.66 will be assigned 1, and so on.

###### Coefficients

It uses a logistic distribution as the underlying distribution, the nice thing about that its units are log odds of increasing from category C or less to cateogry C + 1 or more. It is an assumption of the model that the coefficients are the same to move from 0|1-5 as it is to move from 0-1|2-5, (The 'proportional odds assumption'). Otherwise, you would need one coefficient for each variable and for each cutpoint. This is possible, but is a different model and is very hard to interpret.

So this leaves you with this interpretation (taking `log_pop1` as an example):

For a 1 unit increase in `log_pop1` there is a 3.13 increase in the log odds of the outcome being categories C or less compared to being category C or more. (whatever C is, this is the same, as I explained above)

But because it's difficult to interpret log odds, it is often best to take the exponent of the coefficients.

`exp(3.134) = 22.97`, so for a one unit increase in `log_pop21`, the odds of being category 0 compared to categories 1-5, or  from being categories 0 or 1 compared to being categoies 2, 3, 4 or 5, increases by a *factor* of 22.97 (because we have exponentiated the log odds, we now multiply the odds by `exp(coefficient)` for every one unit increase in it).